# Sending to Distribution groups from workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, email

We recently migrated to `SPO` from `SharePoint Server 2013`. On our SharePoint Server 2013, some of our departments use sending an email from SharePoint lists to distro groups.

We found out by emails not getting received. I have read different places that you can send to security groups that are mail enabled - but that is not an option.

Has anyone else ran into this issue or is this something that is wrong with our environment?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known thing, you have to use mail enabled security groups in order to be able to send it an email.